# Нету прав на запись.

Tags: php, debian, codeigniter

- фреймворк: Codeigniter
- сервер: debian-6.0-i386

пытаюсь загрузить файл с основного сайта на поддомен (см. как cdn) передавая все нужные параметры через get. на поддомене php функцией copy пытаюсь забрать файл. на локалхосте работает, на сервере нет. mkdir/copy - permission denied.

с *nix не знаком. прошу помощи.

**UPDATE:**
/var/www/project - 0501, /var/www/project/data - 0751 и /var/www/project/data/www - 0751. такие права стоят по дефолту при создании через cpanel.

[[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) apache запущен под:

- export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
- export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

Comment: ну а права на файлы под юзером из cpanel вестимо ? вот сделайте на ту директорию куда нужна запись 

    chmod www-data dirname

и вообще Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: только не `chmod`, а `chown`

    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/dir

Answer (score 1):

Слишком мало конкретики. Из вашего вопроса толком не понятно, в чем собственно проблема.

Проверьте права доступа к файловой системе

```
cd /path/to/your/dir/
ls -al .
```

На против нужной папки должна быть надпись в духе `drwxrwxrwx` или `drwxr-xr-x`

Если нужно разрешить чтение и запись, то смотрите справку команды [`chmod`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod). Например, разрешить всем запись можно так:

```
chmod -R a+w .
```

(точка в конце нужна)

`-R` задает рекурсию, т.е. для всех вложенных папок проставит те же права.

Если и тут ругнется, то выполните эту команду от рута:

```
sudo chmod -R a+w .
```

Comment: is_dir не срабатывала из-за грамматической ошибки, а вот проблема с правами осталась. хотя у папки images(рекурсивно) drwxr-xr-x.

а безопасно ставить a+w?

и еще вопрос. мне надо создавать файлы конфигов в /application/config но в директории application лежит .htaccess с Deny from all. что делать?

Comment: зайдите под именем www-data:

     su - www-data -s /bin/bash

попробуйте создать файл в директории с помощью 

    touch /path/to/your/dir/file.txt

если не получится попробуйте сделать cd /path/to/your/dir/ и скорее всего это так-же не получится, найдите в какой из директорий (сверху вниз) нет достаточных прав на чтение и запуск. исправьте нужную директорию с помощью chmod или chown

Comment: `.htaccess` влияет только на поведение apache. Скриптам php на них пофиг, а файловой системе уж и подавно.

Небезопасно, но у вас, скорее всего и так там дыр выше крыши. ИМХО этими вопросами лучше заниматься, когда уже разберетесь, что к чему. А сейчас сделайте так, чтобы оно хотя бы заработало.

Можете попробовать сменить владельца файлов через `chown` (надеюсь, ман нагуглите сами)

Comment: @eicto, да, файл не создает, но в директорию заходит. дело в том что /var/www/project - 0501, /var/www/project/data - 0751 и /var/www/project/data/www - 751. такие права стоят по дефолту при создании через cpanel. что на что изменить?

@Johny, у меня есть дыры только в том случае если сама os из коробки дырявая либо в самом фреймворке дырка, либо я что то пропустил в коде, но это уже другое дело. хоть я не разбираюсь в *nix, я не могу себе позволить делать дырку осознанно.

Comment: а зачем вам там cpanel понадобилась ? от-того и глюки cpanel - известный генератор некошерности

Comment: @eicto я могу сделать на сервере что-нибудь только по мануалу/четким указаниям. при заказе vds LAMP был предустановлен.

Comment: ну вот из-за cpanel мы не можем предсказать как у вас там всё устроено.

Comment: @eicto так я вроде написал какие права. пользователь|группа у файлов/директорий в директории проекта соответствуют созданному юзеру.

Comment: а под каким юзером апач работает ?